# Arithmetic on tikzmark points

Tags: tikzmark

Can I do arithmetic on `tikzmark` points? For example if I have `\tikzmark{A}` and `\tikzmark{B}` can I find their midpoint?

Comment: Thanks Marmot! The \tikzmark part of your example works fine, but the \tikzmarknode is an "undefined control sequence" for me, even after reinstalling MacTex/Tex Live. I guess it's in some version of the tikz packege that has not yet been added to the main distribution?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You can use `calc` for that. In general, the midpoint between `a` and `b` is given by `($(a)!0.5!(b)$)`. One slight subtlety is that you have to prepend `pic cs:` to the `\tikzmark` coordinates, but not for `\tikzmarknode` nodes. The following MWE illustrates this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\begin{document}
Hello\tikzmark{A} something else\tikzmark{B}.\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[red,latex-] ($(pic cs:A)!0.5!(pic cs:B)$) -- ++(0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture} \tikzmarknode{H}{Hello} world and \tikzmarknode{M}{marmots}!\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[red,latex-] ($(H)!0.5!(M)$) -- ++(0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the comparison between `\tikzmark` and `\tikzmarknode`!